# Extract JSON data and embed in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I'm trying to use an API which outputs the results as JSON. The output of the JSON is like this:

```
"status": "ok",
"registry": {
    "id": 110915,
    "name": "John",
    "enlisted": 1359114500
}
```

From that output, I'd like to extract the `name` and print it with php/html. How to do this? I tried stuff like `iframe`, but that didn't work.

Comment: registry.name will have value John...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the name you just need to do this

```
$json = json_decode(@file_get_contents( 'file.json' ));
echo $json->registry->name;
```

But beware, your json code should be like this

```
{
   "status": "ok",
   "registry": 
   {
       "id": 110915,
       "name": "John",
       "enlisted": 1359114500
   }
}
```

you should put your code inside `{` and `}`

Answer (score 2):

since you're going to use php:

```
<?php


// get the json

$data = file_get_contents( 'http://url_to_the_json' );


// decode the json

$data = json_decode( $data );


// see it

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $data, true ) . '</pre>';


// data is now a php object/array/combination.
// I'm not sure how your json file is structured but you can try:

echo $data->registry->name;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Any way of only printing `name`?